# Can't delete attachments in mac mail

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, email, attachments

On the mac mail I used to be able to select a mail, then press “Command” button and “M” to delete an attachment (without deleting the whole e-mail, just delete the attachment). But right now, when I try to delete attachments in some e-mails by pressing those two buttons, it just make a “ding” sound and wouldn’t delete anything. Can you please tell me how to solve this problem?

Since this problem only happening with certain e-mails with attachments, I thought it’s probably something wrong with the attachment. So, I forward that same e-mail back to me (including the attachment and everything), I can delete that attachment by pressing those two buttons. So, I am guessing there is nothing wrong with the files that has been attached.

Macbook Pro OS X 10.6.8
Mail Version 4.5 (1084)

Answer (score 1):

I do not know for the OS X 10.6.8 but on 10.9.5 it works like this

Create new Smart Mailbox

[image: smart mailbox]

Once it is done finding all emails with attachments

Select all or specific one

Under the Messages tab select "Remove Attachment".

**Or**

Create a keyboard shortcut for it

System preferences Keyboard - Shortcuts tab

Select App shortcut

Click on (+) sign)

Select Mail in the Application window

Write "Remove Attachments"

Now choose your favorite keyboard combination for it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the detailed response. But this didn't resolve my problem.